# Lenovo ideapad 320 15IKB Intel i5-8250U consumes more battery on Linux

Tags: drivers, kernel, lenovo, battery, microcode

Lenovo ideapad 320 15IKB, intel i5-8250U consumes more battery (almost double) on Linux compared to Windows 10 while performing similar tasks.
I have tried updating the Kernel to latest version using [Kernel Update Utility](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu). The fan also spins a bit faster on normal use. System info is mentioned below:

```
durrani@ideapad:~$ neofetch
durrani@ideapad 
--------------- 
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: 81BG Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB 
Kernel: 4.18.15-041815-generic 
Uptime: 3 hours, 53 mins 
Packages: 2514 
Shell: bash 4.4.19 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin 
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3] 
Icons: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: Hack 14                                                                      
CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz                                                          
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620                                                                 
Memory: 1793MiB / 11790MiB

durrani@ideapad:~$ dmesg | grep microcode
[    1.755292] microcode: sig=0x806ea, pf=0x80, revision=0x96
[    1.755487] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a Plasmoid for distros having KDE.
[Intel P-State](https://store.kde.org/p/1282623). It have many power and performance profiles. Saves battery a lot but the fan is still spinning a bit fast.